# Building an interface

Tags: go

I wrote the below code that is working fine:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type hashMap interface {
}

type hashMap struct {
    m map[hashable]hashable
    k []hashable
}

type hashMap struct {
    m map[T]T
    k []T
}

// Methods required to enable sort: Len, Less, Swap > start
func (h *hashMap) Len() int {
    return len(h.m)
}

func (h *hashMap) Less(i, j int) bool {
    switch v := h.m[h.k[i]].(type) {
    case int:
        return v > h.m[h.k[j]].(int)
    case float32:
        return v > h.m[h.k[j]].(float32)
    case float64:
        return v > h.m[h.k[j]].(float64)
    case string:
        return v > h.m[h.k[j]].(string)
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func (h *hashMap) Swap(i, j int) {
    h.k[i], h.k[j] = h.k[j], h.k[i]
}

// Methods required to enable sort: Len, Less, Swap > end

// Build Ordered Map methods
func (h *hashMap) from(m map[T]T) hashMap {
    h.m = m
    h.k = make([]T, 0, len(m))
    for key := range m {
        h.k = append(h.k, key)
    }
    return *h
}

func main() {
    inv := new(hashMap).from(map[T]T{"first:": 1, "second": 2})
    fmt.Printf("%v", inv)
}
```

I would like to replace the empty interface `type T interface {}` using something like:

```golang
type T interface {
     Len() int
     Less() bool
     Swap()
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you referring to generic?

Comment: Replace what? And why?

Comment: @Volker, What? replace `empty interface `type T interface {}` updated the question. Why: I started learning go  this week and need to understand it by practice

Comment: @sonus21 yes, I need to do operation `sorting` that requires the item to implement these 3 interfaces, so I'm trying to learn both generic and interfaces in this question.

Comment: why not just https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice ? here, it appears to me, you are going against language design and that you will have hard time accomplish this. I would also suggest to look at code generation tool.

Comment: Fine. Stop what you are trying to do. You will not learn Go by trying to implement generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in general.

Your `hashMap` contains a `map[T]T`. From https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types :

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice. **If the key type is an interface type, these comparison operators must be defined for the dynamic key values**; failure will cause a run-time panic.

(emphasis added).

So this works only if your implementation of `T` has == and != defined. As these operators are not userdefinable only the builtin/predeclared types which define them can be used. So the only types you can use as `T`s are the one you can use as normal map keys anyway. So you gain nothing.

(But honestly I have no idea what your interface `T` is good for, especially given that you cannot use that interface for sorting; or what your code is trying to do. This looks like a XY problem.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, to avoid XY problem, I need to work with `Map` but noticed elements are not sorted in it, and I need my elements to be sorted based on entry, i.e. first element to be first entry and so on, also I need to add functionality of sorting the elements in case there was something missed and not entered in the correct sequence, and would like to make it myself, not by using a 3rd party library.

Comment: @HasanAYousef If you want to sort on entry == time element was added you probably should store a pair (element, sequenceNumber) instead of sorting the keys/values in your map.

Comment: You mean using array of pairs/tuples? I understood there is no tuple in GO!

Comment: @HasanAYousef Come on. Use `struct{val Foo, n int}` as a tuple. A tuple is a logical thing and can be represented in various ways in programming languages. And no, definitively not an array. Arrays are almost never the right thing in Go. Did you do the Tour of GO yet?